# CABasicAnimation jumps back even with removedOnCompletion = FALSE; and fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I want an rotation on my Icon, so it will show its tendency from the month before.

If I go a month before, the Icon jumps back to its normal state and goes up or down.

But I want a smooth Animation!

I tried to built more than one CABasicAnimation instances and it did the trick, but this isn't good!

here is my method:

```
-(void)rotateTrafficAnimation:(UIImageView *)imageView :(float)rotation {
    CABasicAnimation* rotationAnimation;
    rotationAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
    rotationAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: rotation]; // M_PI/2.0
    //NSLog(@"PIHALBE: %f", M_PI/2.0);
    rotationAnimation.duration = 1;
    rotationAnimation.cumulative = YES;
    rotationAnimation.removedOnCompletion = FALSE;
    rotationAnimation.autoreverses = NO;
    rotationAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    rotationAnimation.repeatCount = 0; 
    rotationAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut];

    [imageView.layer addAnimation:rotationAnimation forKey:@"rotationAnimation"];


    //[rotationAnimation autorelease];
}
```

So how can I do it whiteout many of CABasicAnimation instances?

Comment: Have you tried setting:
rotation.fromValue to the current rotation value of your animated presentationlayer?

Comment: thats an good idea i will try

Comment: Can you tell if it worked? Then i will post it as an answer, so you can accept it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what Maverick1st told me in the comments worked out for me, so thanks a lot.

```
rotation.fromValue
```

Did the trick for me.